# How to create a function to generate a list of pre-requisites for a target in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have tried several ways of doing this unsuccessfully.

I have some targets which have pre-requisites of the same structure. So i'm trying to come up with a custom function that simplifies writing these prereqs.

**Prerequisites: all files under "overlay" folder + the file: Dockerfile**

sample folder structure:

```
a/
 + Dockerfile
 + overlay/
          + file1
          + file2
```

Suggested re-use style in Makefile:

```
a_image: $(call GetDockerFiles,$@)
# or whatever else that is recommended
```

Generated target/prerequisites line in Makefile:

```
a_image: a/Dockerfile a/overlay a/overlay/file1 a/overlay/file2
```

How can I achieve this using a re-usable mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this in stages.

Here is the rule you want to construct for `a_image`:

```
a_image: a/Dockerfile a/overlay a/overlay/file1 a/overlay/file2
    ...
```

First you want to construct the list of contents of `overlay/` on the fly:

```
a_image: a/Dockerfile a/overlay $(wildcard a/overlay/*)
    ...
```

Second, you want this approach to work for `b_image`, `c_image` and the rest, so the obvious approach is a pattern rule:

```
%_image: $*/Dockerfile $*/overlay $(wildcard $*/overlay/*)
    @echo THIS WILL NOT WORK
```

This will not work because automatic variables like `$*` are not normally available in the prerequisite list, nor will Make wait until you choose a target before it expands that `wildcard` call. Not normally. But if you use [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) it will work, you just have to be careful about escaping the `$` symbols:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%_image:  $$*/Dockerfile $$*/overlay $$(wildcard $$*/overlay/*)
    @echo Prereqs: $^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It immediately give me what i needed.

Comment: If you were to make this even more reusable and put all those pre-requisites in one function how would that look like? thanks

Comment: that would be something like ```PREREQS := $$*/Dockerfile $$*/overlay $$(wildcard $$*/overlay/*)``` and then ```%_image:  $(PREREQS)```